# XPages Development - which Lotus Domino version is best?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm planning a new XPages application on a new Lotus Domino server and am wondering

a) is it better to choose Domino 9 rather than Domino 8.5.3 FP2?

b) better to choose Domino 64 bit or 32 bit?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I had the choice of server and client. I would pick Domino 9 server and the 9 client/Designer. This will ensure you have the latest and the greatest, with the extension library installed by default. Only reason to go with the OpenNTF extlibx would be to get the relational DB access through xPages.

If the server is dedicated to Domino and has more than 4GB of RAM I would run Domino64.

I am not sure if this question is best asked on this site or on serverfault?

Comment: Add Linux 64Bit as platform so you don't have to deal with NTFS fragmentation

Comment: Agree, go for IBM Domino/IBM XWork Server 9 64-bit and Domino Designer 9 (and always with latest fix packs and interim fixes installed)

Comment: You can still install ExtLibx packages into R9. There is a specific R9 version of the Extension Library now. Also, the most up-to-date version of Social Business Toolkit is only designed to work with R9

Comment: XPages always gets better with the latest version.  So always try and target that if you can.

Comment: does anyone have the address of this "server default" website?